# 2 bower library functions have the same name?

Tags: javascript, bower

I have two libraries that each have a function with the same name, I was wondering if bower had any solutions for this, I've looked through documentation but haven't found any solutions. I figure that this has to be a common issue. I'm sure function names repeat quite often, especially with Javascript's popularity.

Comment: It'll be fine, `_.each` and `$.each` works if they are namespaced correctly otherwise you need to fix that.

Comment: actually it looks like its not 2 bower libraries but one bower library and a library not in bower.

Comment: It won't matter as long as they expose their own objects.